# How to update a SelectizeInput depending on a textInput in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, textinput, selectinput

I have create one app that contains a `textInput` and a `selectizeInput`. Depending on the user's input and if the input can be found in one dataset, you will see all the possibilities according to that `textInput`  in the `selectizeInput`.

[image: image 1]

In this way, if the user introduces a word that it is not in the dataset, the `selectizeInput` can't display any choice.

[image: image 2]

Everything works fine, but I found one problem. If the user starts writing a correct word, the user gets a dropdown list... and then, if the input is removed... the dropdown list is still there (the choices from `selectizeInput` are still there).

[image: image 3]

Here the code:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput("my_input", "Introduce a word"),
  selectizeInput(inputId = "dropdown_list", label = "Choose the variable:", choices=character(0)),
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  my_list <- reactive({
    req(input$my_input)
    data <- as.data.frame(storms)
    
    res <- subset(data, (grepl(pattern = str_to_sentence(input$my_input), data$name))) %>% 
      dplyr::select(name)
    
    res <- as.factor(res$name)
    
    
    return(res)
  })
  
  # This is to generate the choices (gene list) depending on the user's input.
  observeEvent(input$my_input, {
    updateSelectizeInput(
      session = session,
      inputId = "dropdown_list",
      choices = my_list(), options=list(maxOptions = length(my_list())),
      server = TRUE
    )
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Do you know how can I remove the choices from the `selectizeInput` if the user deletes the input?

Thanks very much in advance

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is the `req(input$myinput)`. Hence, if the user deletes the input `my_list()` does not get updated. Instead of `req` you could use an `if` to check whether the input is equal to an empty string:

```
my_list <- reactive({
    if (!input$my_input == "") {
      data <- as.data.frame(storms)
      
      res <- subset(data, grepl(pattern = str_to_sentence(input$my_input), data$name), name)
      
      res <- as.factor(res$name)
      
      return(res)
    } 
  })
```

Comment: Oh god, I was trying to put if statements to check if myinput was empty, but nothing was working. Thanks very much!

Comment: Alternatively, you can listen to the specific event using `my_list <- reactiveEvent(input$my_list, {...})`. This way, the function is really only executed when `my_input` changes, which is slightly better in terms of style.